# rails controllers mini testing after pundit authorize put in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have used pundit in authorization and have decorated my actions in the controller with authorize. I am using Test::Unit (test-unit)  not RSpec. Right after I applied the authorize key word in the actions, the testes started to fail with:

> > Expected response to be a <2xx: success> but, a <302: found> redirected to http://www.example.com/

a sample controller:

```
 index
  authorize User
 end
```

a sample user.test

```
def setup
 sign_in users(:admin)
end

test "should get index" do
 get users_list
 assert response :success
end
```

I have used a user fixture with a user and a password of an admin user.
I am also using Devise for authentication.

any help?

Comment: Your tests are failing because when pundit detects that there is no authorized user, an exception is thrown and it redirects back to previous page. If you login a user within your test, the tests should pass again. Can you clarify what testing framework you are using? What are using for user login/authentication?

Comment: @GregAnswer I have updated my question. Thanks